# How to Send multiple values from Asp.Net WebApi to Angularjs Controller?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

> WebApi Controller.. How to send this value to Angularjs controller (bill = q.TotalBill;)? I have send this (return Ok(gridlist);) into JSON form into angularjs controller

```
public static double bill;  // this is static variable on top of a class
     [System.Web.Http.Route("api/Products/gridpro/{id}")]


           public IHttpActionResult GetGrid(int id)
            {

                var q = db.products.Find(id);
                if (q != null)
                {
                    var check = gridlist.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (check != null)
                    {
                        check.ProductQty += 1;
                        check.TotalAmount = check.ProductQty * check.ProductRate;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        q.ProductQty = 1;
                        q.TotalAmount = q.ProductQty * q.ProductRate;

                        gridlist.Add(q);
                    }
                    q.TotalBill = gridlist.Sum(x => x.TotalAmount);
                    foreach (var item in gridlist)
                    {
                        item.TotalBill = q.TotalBill;
                    }
                    bill = q.TotalBill;   //How to send this value to Angularjs controller

                    return Ok(gridlist);
                }
                else
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
            }
```

> Anagularjs Code: I see all the data into the HTML using this ($scope.gridproducts) but I want to show (bill = q.TotalBill;) this single value into HTML code

```
$scope.OnProChange = function (Pro) {
            var id = Pro.Id;
            $http.get("/api/Products/gridpro/" + id).then(function (response) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))
                $scope.gridproducts = response.data;
            })
        }
```

> HTML code:How I can show total bill value I use {{gridproducts.TotalBill}} this but nothing works.

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in gridproducts">
        <td>
            <a class="delete"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></a>
        </td>
        <td class="name">{{item.ProductName}}</td>
        <td>{{item.ProductRate}}</td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control qty" style="width:50px" onchange="UpdatePurchaseItem('36',this.value)" value="{{item.ProductQty}}">
        </td>
        <td>{{item.TotalAmount}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2"></th>
            <th colspan="2"><b>Total</b></th>
            <th><b>{{gridproducts.TotalBill}}</b></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2"><b></b></th>
            <th colspan="2"><b>Total Items</b></th>
            <th><b>25</b></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Have you tried this? {{gridproducts[0].TotalBill}}

Comment: Thanks man its working ....

Comment: bill = q.TotalBill; how to send this seperate value to angularjs code??

Comment: send back a DTO which has space for both that value and the list...you'll have to make a custom class which has one property to contain the list, and one property to contain the TotalBill variable. Just like a ViewModel, if you've used MVC at all.

Comment: @ADyson  Thanks for your response now my issue is ..bill = q.TotalBill; how to send this seperate value to angularjs code??

Comment: I've just explained it in my previous comment...what did you not understand? You need to change the structure of what your API method returns so that you have space for the TotalBill value as well as the gridlist. Mehmet's answer below is pretty much the same as what I suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want send multiple values to angularjs , you may create complex type for that.
for example,
in c# code

```
Public Class GridDataModel<T>
{
    public T ItemList{get;set;}

    public int TotalBill{get;set}

}
```

then when you return data to js

```
var gridData=new GridDataModel<products>()
{
    ItemList=gridlist,
    TotalBill=q.TotalBill

}

return Ok(gridData);
```

after doing this , you can create another propert for js scope

```
 $http.get("/api/Products/gridpro/" + id).then(function (response) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))
                $scope.gridproducts = response.data.ItemList;
                $scope.totalBill = response.data.TotalBill;
            })
```